# Проблема при десериализация JSON

Tags: c#, .net

Использую RestSharp для отправки запроса на API Yandex, но почему-то переменная result не заполняется.

В переменной response четко виден JSON.

```
 public Result GetLangByString(string str)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("/api/v1.5/tr.json/detect", Method.POST);
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.AddParameter("key", _key); 
            request.AddParameter("text", str);
            IRestResponse response = _restClient.Execute(request);
            RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserializer = new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer();
            var result = deserializer.Deserialize<Result>(response);
            return result;
        }

       public class Result
       {
           public int code;
           public string lang;
       }
```

Если поля заменить на свойства, то все работает. Это какие-то особенности либы или так принято?

Comment: Ну, в WPF, например, тоже поля игнорируются. То, что торчит наружу, по-хорошему должно быть свойством. (А как принято в конкретно вашей библиотеке, я не знаю.)

Comment: Странно, вроде XML нормально и без свойств работает. Наверное, особенность либы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно поля в данном случае будут игнорироваться при десериализации результата. Зависит это от конкретной имплементации метода десериализации. В библиотеке RestSharp этот метод выглядит так:

```
private void Map(object target, IDictionary<string, object> data)
{
        var objType = target.GetType();

        var props = objType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite).ToList();

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var type = prop.PropertyType;

            var name = prop.Name;
            var actualName = name.GetNameVariants(Culture).FirstOrDefault(n => data.ContainsKey(n));
            var value = actualName != null ? data[actualName] : null;

            if (value == null) continue;

            // check for nullable and extract underlying type
            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                type = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }

            prop.SetValue(target, ConvertValue(type, value), null);
        }
    }
```

Как видно из приведенного выше кода, метод получает с помощью рефлексии нужные *свойства* сконструированного объекта `target` типа `T` (в вашем случае это будет класс `Result`) и заполняет их нужными значениями из словаря.

Answer (score 2):

Все верно! Никаких глюков нет! Вы можете менять лишь свойства! А поля это просто переменные, которые не ассоциируются как объекты класса и не обладают таким важным свойством как "ПРИВЯЗКА ДАННЫХ". Вот у вас ничего и не получается с "ПОЛЯМИ"...

Comment: Вроде, для XML и полей достаточно, если не ошибаюсь. Странно, что JSON это не нравится.